# Entity Framework Core 7 relationship

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have two classes `ElementData` and `Socket`.

- An `ElementData` can have multiple `Socket`s
- A `Socket` can have an `ElementData`

So you can nest a series of `ElementData`.

The classes look like this:

```
public class ElementData
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Category { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<SocketData>? Sockets { get; set; } = new List<SocketData>();
}

public class SocketData
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int ParentElementId { get; set; }
    public ElementData ParentElement { get; set; } = new ElementData();

    public int ChildElementId { get; set; }
    public ElementData ChildElement { get; set; } = new ElementData();

    public string ValidElementTypes { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

But if I create a migration, it just connects the `ChildElement` to the parent element and only create `ChildElementId` row in the database.

I was hoping for a database table with columns

```
[Id], [Alias], [ParentElementId], [ChildElementId], [ValidElementTypes]
```

where `ParentElement` has a foreign key to parent `ElementData`, and the `ChildElement` has a foreign key to child `ElementData`.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I think one thing that could trip it up is that you have two ElementData fields in SocketData, but only one Sockets list in ElementData, so it cannot figure out how to connect them. Since this is not a simple case following the conventions, you should [configure the relationships manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration).

Comment: Side notes: (1) Never do this `= new ElementData();` with reference navigation properties (2) never do this `List<SocketData>? Sockets` with collection navigation properties (they can be empty, but not null). As for the concrete question, every reference navigation property must be mapped to a **separate* collection navigation property, because these are separate relationships. In your case, you have 2. The whole question is duplicate unrelated to EFC 7.

Comment: @IvanStoev How should I modify to get it working.. Not quite following :-|

Comment: @MüllerDK Create 2 `List<SocketData>` properties in `ElementData`. Name them as you wish (one could be the currently existing `Sockets` property). Then, using fluent API, map one of the collections to the `SocketData.ParentElement`, and the second one to the `SocketData.ChildElement`. Note that this effectively creates many-to-many self relationship between `ElementData`, with `SocketData` serving as a join entity/table. Clear? :-) Basically the same as in the linked "duplicate", just different class/property names.